# d3.js, color gradient does not change

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg

I am trying to implement a custom component using d3 to visualize data. I am using d3 gradients to render color.

When adding another instance of the component, the color of the gradient remains the same even when `Input() colorList` is changed. Is there something that might be missing?

A sample of the code is here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/spectrum-scale-component

[image]

```html
//colorList = ['#9E0142', '#D53E4F','#090979']

<app-spectrum-scale
[data]="0.7"
[leftLabel]="'Feminine'"
[rightLabel]="'Masculine'"
[middleLabel]="'Neutral'"
[minVal]="-1"
[maxVal]="1"
[colorList]="['#9E0142', '#D53E4F','#090979']"
>
</app-spectrum-scale>  

//colorList = "['#9E0142', '#D53E4F',
                    '#F46D43', '#FDAE61',
                    '#FEE08B', '#FFFFBF',
                    '#E6F598', '#ABDDA4', 
                    '#66C2A5', '#6AA84F',
                    '#38761D']"

<app-spectrum-scale
[data]="0.55"
[leftLabel]="'Negative'"
[rightLabel]="'Positive'"
[middleLabel]="'Neutral'"
[minVal]="-1"
[maxVal]="1"
[colorList]="['#9E0142', '#D53E4F',
                    '#F46D43', '#FDAE61',
                    '#FEE08B', '#FFFFBF',
                    '#E6F598', '#ABDDA4', 
                    '#66C2A5', '#6AA84F',
                    '#38761D']"
>
</app-spectrum-scale>
```

Comment: I have tried to add the ff line of code to remove the contents of the previous svg, `d3.select('svg').remove();` but this ended up deleting the first component, and re-creating the second component

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a unique id to the gradient style when the component initializes. This will ensure that the component rendered, will pick the right gradient.

working code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/spectrum-scale-component

```js
this._id ='id' + (new Date()).getTime();
```

you can then assign this tempId to the 'rect' fill attribute

```js
var tempColorList = this.colorList
var tempId = this._id;

var grad = this._chart.append('defs')
  .append('linearGradient')
  .attr('id', tempId)
  .attr('x1', '0%')
  .attr('x2', '100%')
  .attr('y1', '0%')
  .attr('y2', '0%');

grad.selectAll('stop')
  .data(tempColorList)
  .enter()
  .append('stop')
  .style('stop-color', function(d){ return d; })
  .attr('offset', function(d,i){
    return 100 * (i / (tempColorList.length - 1)) + '%';
  })

var gradValue = 'url(#' + tempId + ')'

var spectrum_bar = this._chart.append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'bg-rect')
  .attr('rx', 5)
  .attr('ry', 5)
  .style('opacity', 0.5)

// assign gradValue id here

  .style('fill', gradValue)
  .attr('height', 15)
  .attr('width', this._barWidth)
  .attr('x', 0)
```